# Consuming vb function in UI

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some code which is developed way back in 2007 or earlier. It is developed in VB. 
It contains .asp pages with function in it.

```
Function Token (ByVal ID, ByVal xyz)
.........
End Function
```

is there any way to use the function. please help me

Comment: Your tags are misleading! This is **ASP**, not **ASP.NET**. I suggest you change you change it to get the proper answer.

Comment: If you are asking if you can use vbscript from an old asp page in asp.net then I think the answer is not trivially and that you are almost certainly better off converting it to VB.NET

Comment: how can i convert it to vb.net